# Angular resource call returning no error/data

Tags: angularjs

Here's my controller call to the service:

```
  Answers.getAnswers($routeParams.questionId, function(answers) {
    console.log(answers);
    $scope.answers = answers;
  });
```

Here's the service:

```
angular.module('intquestApp')
  .factory('Answers', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getAnswers: function(questionId) {
          $resource('api/answers?questionid=' + questionId);
        }
    };
  });
```

I can confirm the resource is there for certain, and I know that the value of `questionId` is accurate.  Am I doing something syntactically wrong?

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation for $resource? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource You code does not really look like anything I see there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your controller code it appears that you require a callback in the factory. Here is the factory code (you had it wrong syntactically)

Factory Code:

```
//Define a module like this
angular.module('intquestApp',[])
  .factory('Answers', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getAnswers: function(questionId,callback) {
          //define resource
          var questionURL = $resource('api/answers?questionid=' + questionId);
          //fire the get call
          questionURL.get().$promise.then(function(answer){
             //return answer in callback
             callback(answer);
          });
        }
    };
  });
```

Controller Code:

```
 Answers.getAnswers($routeParams.questionId, function(answers) {
    console.log(answers);
    $scope.answers = answers;
  });
```

Comment: This code like crashes my entire app... with no errors either.  Really weird.

Comment: can you come up with a plunkr for the problem? and you getting data in the factory function?

Comment: Ahh, the `angular.module('intquestApp',[])` needed to be `angular.module('intquestApp')` I guess... now I can troubleshoot...

Comment: Works perfectly-- changed `get()` to `query()` because an array of data.  Thanks

Comment: great that was some nice coding!!

Answer (score 1):

From [angularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) :

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray).

What you want to use is a promise like explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490560/angularjs-resource-promise)

```
Answers.getAnswers($routeParams.questionId).$promise.then(function (result) {
   $scope.answers = result;
})
```