# AngularJS promises behavior

Tags: angularjs

I have some code using angularJS.
In my application initialization logic, I keep geting an error, but I can't figure out why.
I think this may be a problem with the promise.

Here is my controller:

```
// TeacherCtrl.js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.controllers")
        .controller("TeacherController", TeacherController)
        .config(["$routeProvider", config]);

    TeacherController.$inject = ["DataService"];

    function TeacherController(DataService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.data = {};

        begin(7, 163000001);

        function begin(appId, schoolId) {
            DataService.GetData(appId, schoolId).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }

    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/teacher", {
                "templateUrl": "components/teacher/teacher.html"
                , "controller": "TeacherController"
                , "controllerAs": "vm"
            });
    }
})();
```

And here is my service:

```
// app.services.js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.services")
        .factory("DataService", ApplicationData);

    DataService.$inject = ["KeysResource"];

    function DataService(KeysResource) {
        return {
            "GetData": GetData
        };

        function GetData(appId, schoolId) {
            return KeysResource.load({
                "appId": appId,
                "schoolId": schoolId
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at iniciar (http://my.url/TeacherCtrl.js:18:72)
at new TeacherController (http://my.url/TeacherCtrl.js:15:9)
at .. // angular js code here
```

What it's looks like is that the ".then" function for the promise is not immediately available. Shouldn't it be???

**EDIT**

Here is the KeysResource I've mentioned

```
"use strict";

(function () {
    var restClient = angular.module("restClient", ["ngResource"]);
    var serviceURL;

    restClient
        .factory("KeysResource", ["$resource", function ($resource)
            {
                serviceURL = "http://my.url/service/";

                return $resource(serviceURL, null, {
                    "load": {
                        "method": "get",
                        "url": serviceURL + "load"
                    }
                });
            }]);
})();
```

Comment: `DataService.GetData` does not exist.

Comment: Is `KeysResource` an `ngResource`?  What does `KeysResource.load` look like?  I don't see it in `ngResource` documentation.  I also don't see how `DataService.GetData` doesn't exist as the other three people do... but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: KeysResource.load() must return a promise. You haven't shown us that code, so I can't tell you why that would be.

Comment: `DataService.GetData` still does not exist.

Comment: I've posted the (almost) full code. I think DataService.GetData is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490560/angularjs-resource-promise) question with a similar problem.

The solution is related to $resource, which does not return a promise directly. If I want to use the promise of $resource, I will need to use $promise too, like that:

```
    //TeacherCtrl.js
    function begin(appId, schoolId) {
        DataService.GetData(appId, schoolId).$promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```