# Why my If statement is not working 100 % in JS in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, compare

[image]I have a `$scope.reasonList` which I iterate with `ng-repeat`. But if I go back and forward exactly same page with same data sometimes `if` operatotor is not working and the `$scope.reasonList`  is empty. Exactly same data and same page? Those are strings what I have been comparing. What is happening here and WHY?

```
var reasons = new Array();
var roots = new Array();
var repairs = new Array();
var defectDescsArray = new Array();
defectDescsArray= defectDescSvc.query();
$scope.rma = rmaService.get({id: $routeParams.rmaId});

var rmaHasDefects = rmaDefectSvc.findByRmaId({rmaid: $routeParams.rmaId});
    rmaHasDefects.$promise.then(function (result) {
        alert('result.length:' +result.length)

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 0; j < defectDescsArray.length; j++) {

            if (result[i].rmaHasDefectdescPK.defectdescDefectdescId === defectDescsArray[j].defectdescId) {

                 $scope.showReasonList = true;
                 reasons.push(defectDescsArray[j]);

            }
         }

     }

       $scope.reasonList = reasons;
       //$scope.$apply();
       alert('$scope.reasonList.length' +$scope.reasonList.length);

                    });
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="defect in reasonList">

                <td>{{ defect.returnreasonReturnreasonId.returnText}}</td>
                <td>{{ defect.text}}</td>
            </TR>
        </TBODY>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Angular Service for getting defects**

```
angular.module('defectDescService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('defectDescSvc', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            console.log('------defectDescService-----');
            return $resource(
                    '/RMAServerMav/webresources/com.rako.entity.defectdesc/:id',
                    {},
                    {
                         delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@defectdescId'}}, 
                         update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@defectdescId'} },
                         findByDefectdescId:{
                            url: '/RMAServerMav/webresources/com.rako.entity.defectdesc/defect/:defid',        
                            method: 'GET', 

                            params: {defid: '@defid'},
                            isArray:true}
                    });
        }]);
```

Comment: How does view look like?

Comment: Could you log defectDescsArray after query() function?

Comment: @cyan I edited my question. And yes I can. It is a static list where is more that 100 elements.

Comment: How do you use routes? is the page where you go back with the same controller?

Comment: @cyan no. Those two Pages has controllers of their own. Listcontroller and repair controller.

Comment: Does defectDescSvc.query(); return promise?

Comment: @ cyan - Yes. I edited the question. Although I have the same list in scope as well, but I though first that this is some kind of scope issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**defectDescsArray** is applied with a promise. 
**rmaHasDefects** promise function is called and it is also a promise. 
**rmaHasDefects** promise then guarantee, that the body code is executed after succesful call. 
But problem is, that when executed code is run, you don't have guarantee that **defectDescsArray** is an array with values, because promise call isn't synchronized. That's why, sometime one promise finish first, that is normal case and sometime another promise finish first and then **reasonList** is empty. 
To prove this, log **defectDescsArray** in a promise, and you'll see that sometime it's empty and sometimes not.

```
for (var j = 0; j < defectDescsArray.length; j++) {
    console.log('defectDescsArray length:',defectDescsArray.length);
    if (result[i].rmaHasDefectdescPK.defectdescDefectdescId === defectDescsArray[j].defectdescId) {
```

---

The solution is to synchronise two promises, by using promise on resource.

```
  defectDescsArray= defectDescSvc.query();
    //using a promise and second call is inside a promise to determine not empty //array. 
    defectDescsArray.$promise.then(function (result) {
        defectDescsArray = result;
    $scope.rma = rmaService.get({id: $routeParams.rmaId});

    var rmaHasDefects = rmaDefectSvc.findByRmaId({rmaid: $routeParams.rmaId});
    rmaHasDefects.$promise.then(function (result) {
        alert('result.length:' +result.length)

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 0; j < defectDescsArray.length; j++) {

            if (result[i].rmaHasDefectdescPK.defectdescDefectdescId === defectDescsArray[j].defectdescId) {

                 $scope.showReasonList = true;
                 reasons.push(defectDescsArray[j]);

            }
         }

     }

       $scope.reasonList = reasons;
       //$scope.$apply();
       alert('$scope.reasonList.length' +$scope.reasonList.length);

                    });
});
```

I am basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490560/angularjs-resource-promise) post.

Comment: how to avoid that case?

Comment: it seems that query() returns array from promise. Could you show this method? If you return Promise, you can use then on this promise and after success calling another promise with rmaHasDefects should synchronize it.

Comment: It is basic $resource query. Could you show me with code what you mean with returnin promises?

Comment: Thanks! I got it working before. I just split my code to functions and used promises to be sure that everything is fetched from db. Thanks a lot for your help, it was your comment what helped me a lot! JS is sometimes so horrible :)